# Did the prophet ever establish a formal educational system?

Tags: history

It is a well-known sunnah that Muslims should seek knowledge; the prophet himself would spread knowledge by teaching others (and recommend the same of his followers).  All incidents I know thereof were informal.

**Did the prophet ever formalize an education system (like modern classrooms) to teach in a structured manner?**  If not, when (and by who) was the first such institution established?

Comment: I think school system(Primary, etc.) was introduced by Ibn-Sina(Avicenna in the West). I have also read that Darul-Arqam(the house of Arqam) was the first Madrasa or Islamic School, where the Prophet himself taught different subjects.

Answer (score 1):

Darul Arqm bin Abil Arqam (دار الأرقم بن أبي الأرقم) in makka, the first school and a place of Da'wah.  There The Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) used to teach what was revealed to him.  Furthermore The Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) used to set a day (of the week) where women can come and he used to teach them, [Source](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:954).

Source: [IslamWeb.net](http://articles.islamweb.net/media/index.php?page=article&lang=A&id=157685)

Comment: Was that **a formalized education system to teach in a structured manner?** as OP asked?